# How to get notified about the deletion of a directory watched by FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ioexception, filesystemwatcher

I would like to be informed if a monitored directory gets deleted (/renamed/moved).

Perhaps the following pseudo C# code helps to understand my problem:

```
bool called = false;
var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
fsw.Error += delegate(object s, ErrorEventArgs args) {
    Assert.That(args.GetException() is IOException);
    called = true;
};
fsw.Deleted += delegate(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    Assert.That(e.ChangeType, Is.EqualTo(WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted));
    called = true;
};
Directory.Delete(path);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Assert.That(called, Is.True);
```

If I call the WaitForChanged method an IOException is returned but I is there another way to get notified about this problem?

The mono implementation on Linux works fine and simply returns the Deleted event. But the .Net implementation on Windows seems to differ in the behaviour.

Comment: monitor one level up, and you will get notified

Comment: But I don't what to be informed about all the other changes, because there could be a lot.

Comment: or make the directory remove protected.

Comment: That is not possible in my scenario, because also a renaming is a problem. I would like to monitor all changes in all subdirectories, but would like to stop, if it is not available any more.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second FileSystemWatcher, one level up, and set the Filter and NotifyFilter to monitor only the directory and the events that you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed there is no perfect built-in way to do this. Like Philip mentioned you could use a multi-level approach. But the FileSystemWatcher lacks some stability and can cause problems in fast operating network environments.

So if you need a high performing solution - especially over network - I strongly recommend a polling strategy with a timing that fits your needs or a hybrid of this and the prior to assist the FileSystemWatcher with an availability-poll.

Comment: A second thread waiting for this specific event by polling seems to be the best solution at the moment